# How to enter password then hit enter bash/Chef for Nginx config

Tags: bash, nginx, chef-infra

I am working on setting up basic auth with Nginx, I want to do this with a cookbook. The current way I have it is I have a bash block set up and nothing past that. I am not sure if there is a way to put in what I need using chef/ruby or I need to do bash.

**Command**

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd <username>
```

**bash block**

```
bash 'create nginx login pasword' do
  user 'root'
  cwd '/tmp'
  code <<-EOH
  sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd <username1>
  sudo htpasswd /etc/nginx/.htpasswd <username2>
  sudo htpasswd /etc/nginx/.htpasswd <username3>
  EOH
  action :run
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete cookbook to create a file and add a user.

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/htpasswd

```
# add user "foo" with password "bar" to "/etc/nginx/htpassword" with the default md5 type.
htpasswd "/etc/nginx/htpassword" do
  user "foo"
  password "bar"
end
```

is there a reason why you don't use it?

Comment: I rather not have extra dependancies if don't have to . A good amount of time we will use these cookbooks on nodes that are not internet connected (on prem isolated network)

Answer (score 0):

`htpasswrd` outputs relatively static output. Run those on your workstation and then use an existing secrets management layer (Hashicorp Vault, chef-vault, etc) to distribute the file data. And then use a `file` resource to write it out.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean by running bash commands as a file resource. I understand the secrets management layer and that comes for me after I can get it working with hard coded in on my local.

Comment: On your laptop, run the `htpasswd` commands. Take the file you get as a result and put it in `chef-vault` (or a similar tool). Then use a `file` resource and the `chef_vault_item()` method instead of your `bash` resource.

Comment: that is what I ended up doing in the end. Just made more sense in the end after a while of though.